# Should we remove the "personal-finance" tag? How to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [personal-finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-finance) seems completely redundant for this site, and I want to remove it.  Any objections?

Stack Exchange folks:  I'm also wondering how I would go about doing this.  I don't see any "delete tag" functionality in the moderator tools.  Must I remove it from each question one by one?  Then, how would we prevent somebody from creating it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries -- I destroyed the tag. The correct way to lobby for removal (or blacklisting) is here on meta, as you have.

If it recurs again naturally we can blacklist it as well.